# Android String to ArrayList - Comma Issue

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to convert String to ArrayList but the issue in my case is different from all I saw.

My String is like this:

String data = [0|John|9999999999|No.54, Street|New York, 1|Bash|9898989898|No.5, Road 2|City 2]

***Seperated***:

> **0|John|9999999999|No.54, Street|New York**
>
> **1|Bash|9898989898|No.5, Road 2|City 2**

Here in 1st position it's ID, then name, next contact number, next address, at last city...

data.split will not work here due to **","** in the address field..

Is there any way to convert this string to arrayList or any suggestions for using different method?

Regards,

Lokesh

**EDIT:**
I might have extra field called comments which might have pipe inside that:

Example:

0|Name|Number|Address|City|**I might join|tomorrow**

Here **"I might join|tomorrow"** is single sentence.

**Edit 2:**
I found the solution..

> I just replaced , and pipe in the list with *** and ***** (stars) from server side...

Thanks everyone for suggestions... :-)

Comment: Why won't `data.split` work? Your data is separated by '|' symbols, so `data.split('|');` should be working right? But I think you should tackle the problem by it's root and use a JSON string instead. JSON is parsed far more easily and cleaner.

Comment: Nope not possible in my case:

I get this from data from JSON which has other porperties too..

This is for person details and others...

I might have fileds like this:

3|Name|Number|Address|City|**Comments|Comments Continued**

Comment: I found the solution..
 > I just replaced , and pipe in the list with *** and ***** (stars) from server side...

I had to change whole codeing...  But yeah, Thanks everyone for suggestions... :-) And yes next time will use JSON totally instead of ArrayList - String - ArrayList...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers did not escape the pipe symbol `|`. Thus they wont work.
This is a working example:

```
String s = "0|John|9999999999|No.54, Street|New York";
String[] array = s.split("\\|");
for(String word : array) System.out.println(word);
```

Outcome:

> 0
>   John
>   9999999999
>   No.54, Street
>   New York

[See here](http://ideone.com/WaSOvm)

Comment: I think the pipe "|" doesn't require escape character!

Answer (score 0):

You're fields are seperated by `|`. Try `.split("|")`.

Comment: Please read again in question:

0|Name|Number|Address|City|I might join|tomorrow

Here "I might join|tomorrow" is single sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Split your String by using

```
String[] array = data.split("|");
```

after that do

```
ArrayList<Your Object> arraylist = new ArrayList<Your Object>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex,
`.split("(?<=[a-zA-Z]),")`

This will only match if `,` is preceded by an alphabet. So it will work as long as `,` in your address field follows a number (as in your examples).

Comment: Sorry,

It might have character too...

But, This will work for me as temporary situation... Thanks... :)

If any suggestions It'll be best... :)